# Deriving the wave equation out of $\nabla \times \vec H = \frac{4\pi}{c} \vec J$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation, electromagnetism

I am trying to derive the wave equation presented by Alfven in his 1942 paper

> Based on the electrodynamic equations:
>
> $$\nabla \times H = \frac{4\pi}{c}J$$
>
> $$\nabla \times E = -\frac{1}{c} \frac{dB}{dt}$$
>
> $$B = \mu H$$
>
> $$J = \sigma(E + \frac{v}{c} \times B)$$
>
> Together with the hydrodynamic equation:
>
> $$\rho \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1}{c}(J \times B) - \nabla P$$
>
> Derive the following partial differential equation (which is a one dimensional wave equation):
>
> $$\frac{d^2 H'}{dz^2} = \frac{4\pi\rho}{H_0^2}\frac{d^2 H'}{dt^2}$$

Where:

1) $\sigma$ is the electric conductivity.

2) $\mu$ permeability.

3) $\rho$ is the mass density of the liquid.

4) $J$ is the current density.

5) $v$ is the velocity of the liquid.

6) $P$ is the pressure.

7) $H$ is a quantity used in Physics to express Ampere's Law in terms of the current alone.

8) $c$ is the speed of light.

9) $B$ is the magnetic field.

10) $E$ is the electric field.

11) $H'$ is the variable magnetic field.

I am working assuming perfect conductivity (i.e. $\sigma = \infty$) and no resistance by the medium to allow fluids to pass through it (i.e. $\mu = 1$).

I know how to proceed if we are given Maxwell's equations (which is a set of coupled, first-order, partial differential equations) by applying the curl. However, here we have an additional equation: the hydrodynamic.

How to derive it then? Could you give me hints? The paper doesn't provide more details on the calculation.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's a piece of the original paper:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Note that what I am trying to do is what Alfven said to be 'elementary calculation'; deriving the following wave equation:

$$\frac{d^2 H'}{dz^2} = \frac{4\pi\rho}{H_0^2}\frac{d^2 H'}{dt^2}$$

I know how to get the wave equation out of Maxwell's equations in free space, which are as follows:

$$\nabla \cdot E = 0$$

$$\nabla \cdot B = 0$$

$$\nabla \times E = -\frac{1}{c} \frac{dB}{dt}$$

$$\nabla \times B = \mu \epsilon \frac{dE}{dt}$$

How? Decoupling $E$ and $B$ by applying the curl to both $\nabla \times E$ and $\nabla \times B$. By doing so you get two wave equations; one for $E$ and another for $B$.

Let me show how to do so explicitly for $E$ (more details in *Introduction to Electrodynamics*; Electromagnetic Waves' chapter; Griffiths):

$$\nabla \times (\nabla \cdot E) = \nabla (\nabla \cdot E) - \nabla^2 E = \nabla \times (-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla \times B) = -\mu \epsilon \frac{\partial ^2 E}{\partial t^2}$$

As $\nabla \cdot E = 0$, we end up getting:

$$\nabla^2 E = \mu \epsilon \frac{\partial ^2 E}{\partial t^2}$$

As expected, we end up with the wave equation for $E$.

**So in this problem I think it is just about doing the same but this time with H:**

$$\nabla \times H = \frac{4\pi}{c}J$$

**What I have done is the following (with all steps):**

$$\nabla \times (\nabla \cdot H) = \nabla (\nabla \cdot H) - \nabla^2 H = \frac{4\pi}{c} \nabla \times J$$

We're given $J$, so:

$$\vec \nabla \times \vec J = \sigma \vec \nabla \times ( \vec E + \frac{1}{c}(\vec v \times \vec B))$$

I am stuck in this product:

$$\nabla \times (\vec v \times \vec B)$$

At first I thought $\nabla \times (\vec v \times \vec B)$ could be zero, but **this is not the case**, as we're talking about **transverse waves**; thus $v$ and $B$ are perpendicular **and not** parallel.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what happens if you hit $\nabla \times H = \frac{4\pi}{c}j$ with a curl?

Comment: $\nabla \times (\nabla \times H) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot H) - \nabla^2 H = \frac{4\pi}{c} \nabla \times j$

Comment: Maybe replacing $j$ with its definition will get you somewhere?

Comment: @user721481 thanks, I will work out further this question and update it in a few days

Comment: @user721481 Updated

Comment: On physics.stack someone asked the same [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/528842/derivation-of-alfven-wave) and even put the same photo, if you were able to solve it maybe you could give an answer or a comment with some hint